# how to understand the usage of "add to something"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. Add the grated cheese to the sauce.
> 2. This latest incident will add to the pressure on the White House.
> 3. He added enormously to the national forests in the West.

When I see "add", I think something is followed，then a target is intruduced by "to".

So, sentence 1 is easy to understand for me.

But for sentence 2, does it mean that "the incident" is added into "the pressure" so that "the pressure" is "bigger"(more pressure)?

And for sentence 3,  it sounds very unnatural to me. Does it mean more forests or more acreage? Would be there any difference by replacing "added enormously to" by "enormously increase"?

By the way, why is it "added enormously to" instead of "enormously added to"?

Comment: In (2), _more pressure_ is understood. I find (3) a rather odd sentence. _Presumably_ it means that he increased the area of forested land.

Comment: What @KateBunting said (example #3 is "odd"). Perhaps *He **greatly / significantly extended** the national forests in the West* would be better, but that also very strongly implies *increased the **area** [of forested land]* rather than *increased the **number***. I can't easily think of a succinct way of conveying the second meaning.

Comment: 3 could mean area or number, but I think from context we guess total area/acreage (although he probably didn't go around all the forests expanding the area of each forest, he just expanded some of them). "He added to the cars in the car park" means he put more cars in, it doesn't mean he made the cars bigger.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "add" can either be *transitive* (it has a *direct object*) or *intransitive* (no *direct object*).

In sentence 1, it's *transitive* and "grated cheese" is the direct object.

In sentences 2 and 3, "add" is *intransitive*. It doesn't say *what* is added, only what the target of adding is. In both cases, the reader has to infer the direct object.

In Sentence 2, the inferred direct object is "pressure". We don't need to say it because it's already in the sentence. The incident increased the amount of pressure.

In Sentence 3, it's unclear in the context what "he" added. It may have been money, his career, volunteer labour, knowledge, political action, trees, or anything else. Only the rest of the context for that sentence would make it clear exactly what was added.